# Google Sheets API returning the old values instead of latest

Tags: c#, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Reduced example of the bug: [This](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ldtIl7h75_OIvK8iRadvhMBI7-NUPLWTuuzOjzuxtcs/edit?usp=sharing) sheet has one value in first cell which is the value of `=now()` formula.

This sheet updates (recalculates) every minute as per sheet settings.

[image]

The UI updates as expected very minute. But when I try to get the data via API it is not returning the latest value, instead it returns the past `=now()` value, like 20 minutes ago.

Code:

```
var request = sheetsService.Spreadsheets.Get("1ldtIl7h75_OIvK8iRadvhMBI7-NUPLWTuuzOjzuxtcs");
request.IncludeGridData = true;
var spreadsheet = request.Execute();
Console.WriteLine(spreadsheet.Sheets[0].Data[0].RowData[0].Values[0].FormattedValue); //prints old value
```

Comment: Is more than one user accessing the file?  How did the file get saved?

Comment: The error is there when only one user is accessing. The file made to recalculate every minute through spreadsheet settings, that is how it is getting updated

Comment: The file is shared since one application is writing the file and second is reading.  The writing of a file is buffered and doesn't automatically get saved into the file unless it is FLUSHED.  Windows uses timers to take buffer and write to file and is only done when the buffer get large in the timer function.

Comment: @subject-q, I made a test using `Python` & `Java Script` and I got the same issue. You should report this issue by following the steps in the Google Documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/support#developer_product_feedback)

Comment: I just tested in `Google Apps Script` and had the same issue. It changes to a new time after an hour or so, even by adding `SpreadsheetApp.flush()` with a trigger to run every minute.

Comment: @jdweng no one is writing to the file. it is auto updating every minute

Comment: @GiselleValladares let me know if something has to be added [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/284186691)

Comment: It doesn't matter if it is a user or an app, it is still shared when the file is open more than once.

Comment: @jdweng it is not an app.. it is the google auto recalculate sheet setting. so sheet is not open

Comment: It is still writing to the file.  Excel uses a back door with either JET or ACE to access the data and has a shared option, but sharing doesn't really work on windows.

Comment: It looks good to me @subject-q.